# ArgumentParser: Optional argument with optional value

Tags: python, argparse

If I have an optional argument with optional argument value, is there a way to validate if the argument is set when the value is not given?

For instance:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--abc', nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Would correctly give me:

```
optional arguments:
    --abc [ABC]
```

How do I distinguish between 1 and 2 below?

1. '' => args.abc is None
2. '--abc' => args.abc is still None
3. '--abc something' => args.abc is something

...

Update:

Found a trick to solve this problem: you can use "nargs='*'" instead of "nargs='?'". This way #1 would return None, and #2 would return an empty list. The downside is this will allow multiple values for the arguments to be accepted too; so you'd need to add a check for it if appropriate.

Alternatively you can also set a default value for the argument; see answer from chepner and Anand S Kumar.

Comment: Note that you can convert Namespace to a dict  with with vars(args) and examine that in the script to determine how args have been set .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a different default value for the option. Compare

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--abc', nargs='?', default="default")
>>> parser.parse_args()
Namespace(abc='default')
>>> parser.parse_args(['--abc'])
Namespace(abc=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--abc', 'value'])
Namespace(abc='value')
```

I'm not sure how you would provide a different value for when `--abc` is used without an argument, short of using a custom action instead of the `nargs` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Setting a default value should work. I just found out another way to do it by using nargs='*' instead of nargs='?'. Will update my question in a sec.

Comment: `nargs='*'` does something different; since it allows an arbitrary number of arguments, the default value with 0 is an empty sequence, rather than `None` when the option isn't used at all. It lets you distinguish, yes, but it is further from what you mean to do. Do you really want to allow multiple arguments for `--abc`?

Comment: Both that and setting a default value would work for my problem. I will include both in my question.

Answer (score 14):

With `nargs='?'`, you can supply both a `default` and `const`.

```
In [791]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()    
In [792]: parser.add_argument('--abc', nargs='?', default='default', const='const')
```

If the argument is not given it uses the default:

```
In [793]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[793]: Namespace(abc='default')
```

If given, but without an argument string, it uses the const:

```
In [794]: parser.parse_args(['--abc'])
Out[794]: Namespace(abc='const')
```

Otherwise it uses the argument string:

```
In [795]: parser.parse_args(['--abc','test'])
Out[795]: Namespace(abc='test')

In [796]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--abc [ABC]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --abc [ABC]
```

Comment: Additionally, you can supply a `choices` argument to restrict the argument's value. With `'foo', choices=[False], const=True, default='default,' nargs='?'`, `foo` is `True` when present without argument, `False` if explicitly made so, and easily filterable and thus optional otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the standard way, but you can set `default` argument to something , and then that value would be used in case `--abc` is not in the argument list.

Example code -

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--abc', nargs='?', default="-1")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Result -

```
>python a.py
Namespace(abc='-1')

>python a.py --abc
Namespace(abc=None)

>python a.py --abc something
Namespace(abc='something')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Setting a default value should work. I just found out another way to do it by using nargs='*' instead of nargs='?'. Will update my question in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this to have a command-line arg for multiprocessing. Specifying `--multi` uses all cores and given an arg specifies a number of cores, e.g., `--multi 4` for four cores.

```
parser.add_argument("-mp", "--multi", type=int, nargs="*", help=multi_text)
```

Parsing logic is then:

```
    if (args.multi == None):
        num_cores = 1
    elif (args.multi == []):
        num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    elif (len(args.multi) == 1):
        num_cores = args.multi[0]
    else:
        print("Invalid specification of core usage.")
        sys.exit(1)
```