# Python argparse check if flag is present while also allowing an argument

Tags: python, argparse

How do I check if the flag `--load` is present?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import os 

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--load', nargs='?', metavar='path', help='Load all JSON files recursively in path')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)
```

Calling the script with `--load` outputs the following:
`Namespace(load=None)`

I can't omit `nargs='?'` and  use `action='store_true'` as I'd like to allow an argument to be passed, for example `--load abcxyz`.

Adding `action='store_true'`and `nargs='?'` produces an error of:

```
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--load', nargs='?', metavar='path', help='Load all JSON files recursively in path', action='store_true')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1334, in add_argument
    action = action_class(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nargs'
```

Comment: With '?' you can specify `default` and `const` parameters.  Try them, or lookup `const` in the docs (or previous SO `argparse` questions).

Comment: A `store_true` action is by definition `nargs=0`; it takes no argument.  No use trying to redefine it to take a different `nargs`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31817368/901925

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArgumentParser: Optional argument with optional value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815660/argumentparser-optional-argument-with-optional-value)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `in` operator to test whether an option is defined for a (sub) command. And you can compare the value of a defined option against its default value to check whether the option was specified in command-line or not.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import os 

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--load', 
    dest='load', nargs='?', default=None, 
    help='Load all JSON files recursively in path')

args = parser.parse_args()

'some_non_exist_option' in args # False
'load' in args # True
if args.load is not None:   
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In the same above snippet, for checking --load flag:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import os
name = None
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--load', metavar='path', help='Load all JSON 
files recursively in path')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.load)

if args.load:
    name = args.load
```

will assign `name` to `abcxyz`, else will be none.
If i am able to understand your problem, the above code actually does what you are looking for.
The `name` variable is not really required , just used as an example.

Comment: The question was "How do I check if the flag --load is present?" I don't see how this answer answers that.

Comment: `args.__contains__('load')` ? is it what you're looking for.