# python argument with or without value, specified or not

Tags: python, argparse, argv

Scenario is as follows:

I need to implement a command line argument system that allows both

`-p <value>`

and

`-p`

(no value for -p given)

Is there any way to achieve this using argparse, or will I have to manually parse sys.argv?

Thank u so much!!!

Comment: [ArgumentParser: Optional argument with optional value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815660/argumentparser-optional-argument-with-optional-value) - `nargs='?' with `const` and `default`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will set args.param to `None` when the option is not specified (or specified without parameter) and to the specified value otherwise

```
import argparse

UNSPECIFIED = object()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-p', action='store', dest='param', default=UNSPECIFIED, nargs='?')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.param == UNSPECIFIED:
    print("Param unspecified")
else:
    print(args.param)
```

Comment: obviously, not working. If `-p` is specified without arguments, it will fail.

Comment: edited to add `nargs`, now will accept `-p` without value

Comment: There's no way to know If `-p` was not specified or it was without argument (`param` shall be None in both cases) out of the box. Yet, the workaround of `if('-p' in sys.argv):` is simple enough; so I'll mark it as answer. Thank u so much!!!

Comment: With nargs='?', you can also specify a 'const' parameter

Answer (score 8):

What you need is three states,   absent, present, present with value.

The argparse module provides at least two simple ways to do this.

For the simplest, and most flexible, you only need add **action='store'** and **nargs='*'**.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-p', action='store', nargs='*')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.p is not None:
    print( '-p present' )
else:
    print( '-p not present' )

print( '-p value', args.p )
```

Here is your output for this method:

```
# ./testpar.py
-p not present
-p value None

# ./testpar.py -p
-p present
-p value []

# ./testpar.py -p something
-p present
-p value ['something']

# ./testpar.py -p something anotherthing
-p present
-p value ['something', 'anotherthing']
```

For the second method, you can set a specific value for the second of the three states, **const=somevalue** and **nargs='?'**.   This method supports one value only, and the value for 'const' has to be something that would not be a valid input by the user.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-p', action='store', const='NoValue', nargs='?')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.p:
    print( '-p present' )
else:
    print( '-p not present' )

print( '-p value', args.p )
```

And here is your output for the three cases,

```
# ./testpar.py
-p not present
-p value None

# ./testpar.py -p
-p present
-p value NoValue

# ./testpar.py -p something
-p present
-p value something
```

Comment: How does arparse disambiguate between `./test -p pval posarg1` and `./test -p posarg1`?

Comment: Answer: it can't disambiguate. So, this narg=? is not really useful when you also have positional arguments.

Comment: @alexei  The first one works for your case.   I just fixed a typo.  Try it.

Comment: just tried again with nargs='?' and nargs='*', neither can disambiguate. The first positional argument is interpreted as if it was the value of the flag argument.

Comment: Using  parser.add_argument('-p', action='store', nargs='*'),  I get none if -p not specified, or a list with zero or one or two items in the list depending on how many arguments were provided.   I actually use this in deployed code, for years, it works.

Comment: We must be referring to different cases, because it certainly cannot disambiguate:
`$ python arg.py -f farg posarg`
`usage: arg.py [-h] [-f [F ...]] posarg`
`arg.py: error: the following arguments are required: posarg`

Comment: @alexei   I just edited to show the output for the case with two arguments.   There is no question that it works.  Try copying the first code sample exactly, and run it as listed.

Comment: You are still missing the case. The case that cannot work involves two parser.add_argument() calls, one for a flag, and another for a positional argument. See the help output in my previous comment here. Does that clarify?

Comment: @alexei  I see, it did not occur to me that that could be your case    It is mentioned in the documentation for argparse at python.org.    They tell you that it does not make sense.   What they mean is that it is inherently ambiguous.  Any solution will be an unstable kluge at best.

Comment: If I'm not missing something, `action="store"` is the default, so this argument can be omitted.

Comment: @luator, try it and let us know

Comment: @DrM I did and at least for me it is working without.  Tested with Python 3.10 in case the version matters.

Comment: @luator, great, thanks for taking the time.  I will try to find a moment to confirm and edit accordingly